# Reuse Quorum cards with "Give this card to another player"

Tags: battlestar-galactica

Many quorum cards feature an effect that says "give this card to another player". That player then receives some kind of passive privilege (does not require an action) like determining the next FTL jump destination.

My question is: Can the receiving player use that card's action too (and pass it on to yet another player) or is it only to remind people of the passive privilege?

My instinct tells me that it's only a reminder but I couldn't find a clarification for either alternative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Even if this were allowed, how would the other person play it?  It's not creating a new hand of cards and new delegated political powers.

There's no precedent in-game for cards to be 'read' twice.

And if this worked this way it would be *deeply weird*.

For those reasons I say no "pass[ing] it on to yet another player".

Comment: "I say no passing" in your answer is a little misleading.  The cards DO say to give them to the other player.  It's just that they are not **playable** by that second player - they don't have a Quorum hand, they just have an effect placed on them by the Quorum card.  Technically you still pass the card to them though.

Comment: Well, there are plenty of games (some CCG's for example) where it is common for a card to be controlled by different players over the course of a game.

Comment: @Kempeth yes, but this is not a CCG. The intent of these cards is that the passive effect applies if you've been "given" the card, but having it in your hand allows you to take the action. No additional passing of the card.